# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, pdo

I got this error when I used GROUP BY in the query below

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'table_name.total_ttc' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in ............

```
function situationsList(){ 
    $query = "SELECT `ref_s`, `total_ttc`, `created_at`, `mode_pay` FROM `situations` GROUP BY ref_s ";
    $statement = $GLOBALS['PDO']->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();

    $data = array();
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

The query works just fine in localhost but when I upload it on server I get that error!

Comment: Because your server has stricter settings

Comment: The query doesn't make much sense, why have you got a group by without any kind of aggregate function?

Comment: have you looked in to the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I have to use the group by ref_s because one SITUATION have a reference number and can have one or multiple ITEMs. I want get a list of SITUATIONS and I dont want to list them with the same  reference number

Comment: Thank you! I solved the issue by removing ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Comment: It would be better to make the query compliant with modern standards instead